# Want to convert the associative array data into CSV format

Tags: php, csv

I have an associative array containing some keys like (`[0-50]`, `[50-100]`) and their respective values like `23`, `443`.

I want to generate a CSV format file in which I want to have two columns like `Distance` and `Trips`. And the keys which are in array must be in the column of `Distance` and the values which are in the array must be in the column of `Trips`.

I have tried this using `fputcsv()` but it is not responding correctly.

```
<?php

$file = fopen("/tmp/abc.csv", 'w');

fputcsv($file, array(
    'Distance', 'Trips'
)); 

foreach($ed as $k=>$v) {
    fputcsv($file, $v);
}

fclose($file);
```

$ed response is this .

```
Array
(
    [0-50] => 880
    [50-100] => 5
    [100-150] => 1
    [550-600] => 1
)
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: $file = fopen("/tmp/abc.csv", 'w');
                                                                                                                        fputcsv($file, array('Distance', 'Trips'));
   
   foreach($ed as $k=>$v)
   {
        fputcsv($file, $v);
   }
   fclose($file);                                                                                  where $ed is the array which is in the form of -> Array( [0-50]=>21  [50-100] => 45)

Comment: please add $ed to your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fputcsv` expects an array of values like:

```
 $ed = array("val1", "val2", "val3", ... );
```

You are passing a value at a time in `fputcsv($file, $val);` which won't work or give unexpected results.

In order to get the values of your array, do the following:

```
foreach($ed as $k=>$v) {
    $row = array ( $k, $v );
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}
```